# counting duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I know this topic has been discussed million times, but I am having a strange output. I am trying to accomplish a job where a sql query will count the number of duplicate + non-duplicate rows. Basically I have the following table:

```
ID 
865      
501     
501     
501
502
865
865
```

My query is

```
select id, count(*) as total from master_huts group by id
```

And I am getting this

```
ID     Name
0      (some weird number)
501    3
502    1
865    2
```

It's pretty straight forward, but not sure where I am wrong.

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `master_huts` (
 `hutids` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Check for empty rows in table

Comment: @echo_Me The problem is ^

Comment: @user3671491 how is defined your id column ? int or varchar ?

Comment: you sure you dont have 0 in your table or someother values ? look demo here it works fine http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7195/1

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that replicates the problem?

Comment: what is the total records in the table and what is that some weird number?

Comment: @Barmar have done sqlfiddle :) , and looks fine.

Comment: @echo_Me Update the question with table structure.

Comment: if you have large table ,try do this to see if you have 0 value `select id from yourtable  where id = 0`

Comment: @echo_Me Thanks mate.You saved my day. There were 0. The table has got about 1.5 million records and I was very much sure that the ID doesn't contain any zero. Thanks once again. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
select count(id) as ocurences, id from master_huts group by id
```

Comment: It means you really have a row with id=0

Comment: My mistake as usual. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Just use id in count instead of *

like this...

```
select id, count(id) as total from whatever group by id
```

Comment: Did that but still I am getting a 0 as first row

Comment: Are you sure your table has exact the same data given by you?

Comment: Solved :). my mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

try this and see if you still get anything weird:

```
select id, count(*) as total from master_huts where id != 0 group by id;
```